# Adding input nodes on an intermediate layer

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I am trying to implement a ConvNet binary classifier on a set of images (2D arrays). I realize that the first convolutional layers are essential for feature extraction. I, however, have additional input parameters which could help in classification. The idea is to append additional nodes to the first fully connected layer so that I may use a feed-forward neural network for the eventual classification. Is this in anyway possible with the keras API? I would also like to know if there is a way of pulling the output of intermediate layer through the Sequential model architecture. The following code defines the model:

```
new = Sequential([
      Conv2D(8, [3,3], activation='relu', padding ='same'),
      MaxPool2D([2,2], 2, padding='valid'),
      Conv2D(16, [3,3], activation='relu', padding='same'),
      MaxPool2D([2,2], 2, padding='valid'),
      Flatten(),
      Dense(256),
      Dense(64),
      Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
    ])
```

Comment: See [Multi-input and multi-output models](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/#multi-input-and-multi-output-models) and [How can I obtain the output of an intermediate layer?](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-obtain-the-output-of-an-intermediate-layer).

Comment: You should also check Functional API with @jdehesa 's mentions.

Answer (score 0):

> I realize that the first convolutional layers are essential for feature extraction. I, however, have additional input parameters which could help in classification. The idea is to append additional nodes to the first fully connected layer so that I may use a feed-forward neural network for the eventual classification. Is this in anyway possible with the keras API?

Yes it's possible, please refer sample code with an intermediate input in same network using Keras Functional API

```
from keras.layers import Dense, Input, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Flatten, Dense, concatenate
from keras.models import Model

# feature extraction from gray scale image
inputs = Input(shape = (28,28,1))

conv1 = Conv2D(16, (3,3), activation = 'relu', padding = "SAME")(inputs)
pool1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2), strides = 2)(conv1)
conv2 = Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation = 'relu', padding = "SAME")(pool1)
pool2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2), strides = 2)(conv2)
flat_1 = Flatten()(pool2)

# feature extraction from RGB image
inputs_2 = Input(shape = (28,28,3))

conv1_2 = Conv2D(16, (3,3), activation = 'relu', padding = "SAME")(inputs_2)
pool1_2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2), strides = 2)(conv1_2)
conv2_2 = Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation = 'relu', padding = "SAME")(pool1_2)
pool2_2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2), strides = 2)(conv2_2)
flat_2 = Flatten()(pool2_2)

# concatenate both feature layers and define output layer after some dense layers
concat = concatenate([flat_1,flat_2])
dense1 = Dense(512, activation = 'relu')(concat)
dense2 = Dense(128, activation = 'relu')(dense1)
dense3 = Dense(32, activation = 'relu')(dense2)
output = Dense(10, activation = 'softmax')(dense3)

# create model with two inputs
model = Model([inputs,inputs_2], output)
```

> I would also like to know if there is a way of pulling the output of
>   intermediate layer through the Sequential model architecture.

Yes, For any operation which is to be carried out on the layers of a Keras model, first, we need to access the list of `keras.layers` object which a model holds

```
model_layers = model.layers
```

Each Layer object in this list has its own `input`and`output` tensors (if you're using the TensorFlow backend)

```
input_tensor = model.layers[ layer_index ].input
output_tensor = model.layers[ layer_index ].output
```

Below am showing how to pull output from intermediate layer from Sequential Network

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(8, [3,3], input_shape=(28,28,1), activation='relu', padding ='same'))
model.add(MaxPool2D([2,2], 2, padding='valid'))
model.add(Conv2D(16, [3,3], activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPool2D([2,2], 2, padding='valid'))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(256))
model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.summary()
```

To pull output of 4th Layer,

```
output_tensor = model.layers[3].output
print(output_tensor)
```

Output:

```
Model: "sequential_1"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 28, 28, 8)         80        
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2 (None, 14, 14, 8)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 14, 14, 16)        1168      
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling2 (None, 7, 7, 16)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 784)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 256)               200960    
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 64)                16448     
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 65        
=================================================================
Total params: 218,721
Trainable params: 218,721
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________

Tensor("max_pooling2d_2/MaxPool:0", shape=(None, 7, 7, 16), dtype=float32)
```